# Find common elements in a nested list

Tags: kdb

How to find common elements in nested list, please suggest better solution.

```
q)list2:((12 18 23 25 45); (7 12 18 24 28); (1 5 8 12 15 16 18))
q){ (x 0) inter (x 1) inter (x 2)} [list2]
  12 18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for [over (/)](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#over)

```
q)(inter/)(12 18 23 25 45;7 12 18 24 28;1 5 8 12 15 16 18)
12 18
```